# Convert Double Format 10000.00 to 10,000.00 in Java

Tags: java, format, double

I am quite new with Java.

Any idea on how to convert the format of 10000 to 10,000.00 in double variable?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I suggest you read the Oracle tutorials on the basics of Java, you can start with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
double d=10000;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0,000.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Output

```
10,000.00
```

Comment: The output of  **double d=11111;** will be **10,000.00** .. is this what you want ? or you want to be **11,111.00** .. if so use **#** rather than **0** in the pattern.

Comment: @MuhammadHamed `11111` will give `11,111.00` by using this pattern

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
System.out.println(value + " " + pattern + " " + output);
```

check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) for more info

Comment: Output of 10000 is coming to 10,000 using `###,###.###`, instead use `###,###.00` to get it `10.000.00`

Answer (score 1):

Check this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html),
it is definitely more than enough . In your case the format is **#,###.00**

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(10000));
```